# Where does the ResponseHandler go?

Tags: java, apache, http

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/json");

ResponseHandler<MyJsonObject> rh = new ResponseHandler<MyJsonObject>() {

    @Override
    public JsonObject handleResponse(
            final HttpResponse response) throws IOException {
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        if (statusLine.getStatusCode() >= 300) {
            throw new HttpResponseException(
                    statusLine.getStatusCode(),
                    statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
        }
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new ClientProtocolException("Response contains no content");
        }
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        ContentType contentType = ContentType.getOrDefault(entity);
        Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent(), charset);
        return gson.fromJson(reader, MyJsonObject.class);
    }
};
MyJsonObject myjson = client.execute(httpget, rh);
```

Apache gives the above example, but I've never seen that syntax. It looks like the definition of ResponseHandler() is being assigned to a variable; no idea what this means. Is all this code in a single method of a class?

Comment: Have you never heard of anonymous class?

Comment: No I have not. I wasn't sure what this was.

Comment: Here is a tutorial on that - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html.